# Why does applying an objects matrix to a location fail?

Tags: python

I am trying to get global coordinates of a point for an addon I'm creating.

If an object has no transformations, the coordinates I'm grabbing work, and also if there is either a scale or a translation. Yet, any rotation transformation produces incorrect results:

1. Open Blender, *File > Load factory settings*
2. Hit <kbd>Numpad 1</kbd> to go to front ortho view
3. Hit <kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Z</kbd>, <kbd>4</kbd><kbd>5</kbd> to rotate the default cube 45 degrees around z axis
4. Hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> to toggle edit mode and select the upper leftmost vert in this view
5. Hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Tab</kbd> to toggle edit mode off and on again
6. Select scripting layout
7. Run this code in *Python Console*:

   ```
   ob = bpy.context.object

   for point in ob.data.vertices:
       if point.select:
           print(point.co * ob.matrix_world)
   ```
8. Press <kbd>N</kbd> in *3D View* panel to bring up point coords, switch to **Global** and compare coords from python console, these are different:

   - From python console: `Vector (0.0000, 1.4142, 1.0000)`
   - From N panel: X: `-1.41421, Y: -0.0000004, Z: 1.00000`

So, what am I doing wrong? Here's my code:

```
class GrabPointFromActive( bpy.types.Operator ):
    bl_idname = "mct.grabpointfromactive" # Check the blender precedent here for naming
    bl_label = "Grab From Active Point"
    bl_description = "Grabs coordinates from selected vertex in edit mode"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    def execute(self, context):
        addonData = bpy.context.scene.mct_data
        prims = bpy.context.scene.mct_data.primList
        ob = bpy.context.object

        # fix later, only allow execution when a single vert is selected, otherwise warn
        # fix later, check if this is a mesh first before toggling, we need this so most recent active selection is used
        bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
        bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
        for vert in ob.data.vertices:
            if vert.select:
                prims[addonData.activeListItemIndex].point = vert.co * ob.matrix_world

        return {'FINISHED'}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When applying an objects transformation matrix to a vertex, you need to multiply:

```
Matrix * Vector
```

However your example does:

```
Vector * Matrix
```

This behavior matches `numpy` and other math libraries.