# Create bones on vertices in Python

Tags: python, scripting, rigging, armature, bones

I want to generate several bones on vertices with python. I have figured out how to make an Armature Object, and how to make edit bones within it. Now I need to get these bones onto their appropriate vertices. Can I create them on certain points in the first place? Or can I somehow move them there?

Do I use head, head_local, translate, matrices, or something else?

Comment: if bones are connected you have to move head and tail with head_local tail_local to vertex coordinates (given that armature and object has the same loc-rot-scale )

Comment: I am still figuring out how to even connect them. I am making a bone on every 4th point down an edge loop. I need to make the bones in the right place, and then have them be connected to each other.

Comment: check [this page](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:IT/2.5/Py/Scripts/Cookbook/Code_snippets/Armatures) it has all what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Bmesh to get the required coordinates.

```
import bpy, bmesh #first import bpy and bmesh
obj = bpy.context.active_object

if obj.mode == 'EDIT':
    bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(obj.data)
    vertices = bm.verts

else:
    vertices = obj.data.vertices

verts = [obj.matrix_world * vert.co for vert in vertices] #this should get your coordinates as tuples.

plain_verts = [vert.to_tuple() for vert in verts]
for I in range(0,482):#where you'd like to set your bones i chose from 0 - 482 because i wanted to fill a sphere.
    print(plain_verts[I])#so you can see your data
    bpy.context.scene.cursor_location = (plain_verts[I])#move the cursor to the vertices position.
    bpy.ops.object.armature_add()#this uses blenders menu method to add the bone, at the cursor.
```

After like 3 minutes of searching online I was able to [find this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1311/how-can-i-get-vertex-positions-from-a-mesh), and by reading the commands in Blender easily figured out how to create a bone.

Is this not what you're looking for?

Or did you want to know how to join and rotate bones?

because that would be

```
bpy.data.objects['selectedbonesbones'].select = True
bpy.context.scene.objects.active = bpy.data.objects["selectedbonesbones"]
```

and [look here to rotate the bones](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28159/how-to-rotate-a-bone-using-python#28166) in pose mode.

If you want to rotate in object mode it should be something like

```
bpy.data.objects['armature'].rotation_euler[0] = 1
bpy.data.objects['armature'].rotation_euler[1] = 2
bpy.data.objects['armature'].rotation_euler[2] = 3
```

If you want to rotate in edit mode, well I haven't found anything very useful but you can [try this, line 335 to 364](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/release/scripts/modules/bpy_types.py;e60fb0fd294577948f8ce0f07817b98d1b3024fe%24335). Tell me if it works!

Comment: sidenote 
you can do something like:
 
 
import bpy
 
 
bpy.data.objects["Armature.042"].pose.bones["Bone.006"].location[0]=0
for pose mode in bpy.

Comment: gotta be out of edit mode for this to work. and bpy.ops.object.armature_add() will add an armature, not a bone