# How to convert mesh back to text object?

Tags: mesh, text-object

I converted text to mesh now i want to convert mesh to text, how  i can do it?[image]

Comment: I think you can't. Maybe you can undo (ctrl-z). Usually, I keep a copy (maybe hidden in a layer) of the text object that I convert to mesh, just to be able to start again from the text...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It cannot be done.  I mean, as m.ardito states, you can undo, or duplicate the text and keep a copy for backup, but converting to mesh is a one way, destructive action.

Answer (score 0):

while not being able to turn it back into its original state, you can in fact grab every vertex and copy the material automatically. But you can never reside it back to its original state.

https://youtu.be/OEkrQGFqM10 should help a little

you'll probably want the vertex location command
which can be found here [How can I get vertex positions from a mesh?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1311/how-can-i-get-vertex-positions-from-a-mesh)
and basic location command is
bpy.context.object.location.x
bpy.context.object.location.y 
&
bpy.context.object.location.z