# How do you grab the cylinder's mesh data using python?

Tags: python, mesh, camera

For my current project, I need to grab the mesh data from a randomly generated cylinder. I would like to get the xyz location of all the vertices, see pics below to get a general idea of what I want to do.

[image]

[image]

Another very important thing is I would also like to grab the camera metadata as well. Eg FOV, location etc. I can then save the data to a text file for later use. Basically, the goal is if I reverse the process and read the metadata stored in that text file I should be able to recreate the same cylinder in the same perspective with the same camera angle! I am not new to python but I am a newbie to Blender's api.

TLDR: Grab all vertice coordinates from the cylinder and corresponding basic camera info as well.

Edited: The dots are just random doodles to get my point across.

Comment: Found this thread for mesh , I still need to get info from the camera. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1311/how-can-i-get-vertex-positions-from-a-mesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code that made everything work

**Getting the mesh data from the model:**

```
ob = bpy.data.objects['Cylinder']
verts = [verts.co for vert in ob.data.vertices]
```

**Getting the location and rotation data from camera:**

```
camera_location = np.round( list( bpy.data.objects['Camera'].location ), 3)
camera_rotation = np.round( list( bpy.data.objects['Camera'].rotation_euler ), 3)
```

I had to use numpy "np" to round down the outputs, I did the same thing for verts.