# adding or filling export to csv/excel fill

Tags: export, csv, spreadsheet

adding or filling export to csv/excel fill test

Comment: Are you familiar with python?  I just tried https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1311/how-can-i-get-vertex-positions-from-a-mesh on a cube and it worked.  You could then `import csv` and pass in the list of vertices you get and specify the disk location you want the csv file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this from the GUI, change your file output location from my directory to whatever you want to call it, and select the correct object for csv_obj

````
import bpy
import csv

csv_obj = bpy.data.objects['Cube']

out_list = []
for i, vert in enumerate(csv_obj.data.vertices):
    out_list.append(vert.co)

print(out_list)

file = open('/home/harrison/Documents/blender_stack.csv', 'w+', newline='')
with file:
    write = csv.writer(file)
    write.writerows(out_list)

```
````