# Why is the vertex position obtained with Python distorted?

Tags: python, scripting, vertices

For a project with Godot, I need a path object, along which I can move a vehicle. Since I modeled the railroad track in Blender 3.3 using a **Bézier Curve** and a **Curve Modifier**, I **converted** the Bézier **Curve to a Mesh** and used a simple Python script (pseudo-code: see below) to export the **Vertex Coordinates** of my track generation curve into a json file.

When importing the vertex coordinates into the Godot Path Object, a distortion in some of the rounded curve sections occur (see image below). The distortion is so bad that the Path is not usable for its intended purpose.

[image: Comparison Curve: Blender vs. Godot]

The image shows that the path in Godot shifts drastically out of the center position along the curved segments in the negative x coordinate regime, whereas in Blender the "same" path stays nicely centered everywhere. Since the **mesh is completely symmetrical** (placed all the points via coordinates) and **has no modifiers applied to it** (had issues previously with the mirror modifier destroying the vertex topology/ordering), this is strange. It is definitely not an issue with Godot (verified this very thoroughly). The asymmetry is present as soon as the data is acquired via Python within Blender (even before the export into the file). Plotting the histogram of the coordinates (plot below) shows a significant asymmetry along the x direction 
(e. g. x = -4.3 m vs. x = 4.3 m) as well as the z direction (using the Godot convention here: y-up).

[image: Coordinate Histogram]

The asymmetry along the z direction is not as pronounced as its counter part, but cannot be attributed to histogram binning (bin size = 0.1 m) either.

### Workflow

1. Add *Array Modifier* to `sleeper` and `railProfile` meshes.
2. Add *Curve Modifier* to `sleeper` and `railProfile` meshes with following settings:
   `Curve Object: trackCurve`, `Deform Axis: -Y` (other settings do not work at all; however, this returns the desired output flipped, so step 7 and step 8 become necessary to flip it).
3. Select `sleeper` mesh, `railProfile` mesh as well as the `trackCurve` Bézier Curve and duplicate them with `Shift + D`.
4. On the mesh duplicates, apply first the *Array Modifiers*, then the *Curve Modifiers*.
5. Select the mesh duplicates and join them with `Ctrl + J`. Rename the resulting mesh to `track`.
6. Select the `trackCurve` Bézier Curve duplicate and convert it to a mesh via
   `Object Context Menu -> Convert to -> Mesh`. Rename it to `trackPath`.
7. Select the `track` and `trackPath` meshes. Rotate them by 180° around the y axis via
   `R + y + 180` to rectify the orientation issues induced by step 2.
8. With both meshes still selected, apply the rotation to prevent any issues with `Ctrl + A` and `Apply -> Rotation`.
9. Make sure that only the `trackPath` mesh is selected and run the Python vertex coordinate export script.

The code (based upon the answer to [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1311/how-can-i-get-vertex-positions-from-a-mesh)) I use to write the json file is as follows:

```
import bpy, bmesh

###########################################################################################################
######## OBTAIN Vertex Coordinates ########################################################################
### source: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1311/how-can-i-get-vertex-positions-from-a-mesh ###
###########################################################################################################
obj = bpy.context.active_object

if obj.mode == 'EDIT':
    # this works only in edit mode,
    bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(obj.data)
    verts = [vert.co for vert in bm.verts]

else:
    # this works only in object mode,
    verts = [vert.co for vert in obj.data.vertices]

# coordinates as tuples
plain_verts = [vert.to_tuple() for vert in verts]

###########################################################################################################
######## EXPORT Vertex Coordinates ########################################################################
###########################################################################################################
exportString = "{\n"
_pointCounter = 0
_iterationLength = len(plain_verts)-1

# formatting the data: x,y,z (Blender) -> x,0,y (Godot) + json specific syntax
# x = element[0], y = element[1], z = element[3]
# z != 0 to prevent any issues with float precision 
# (Path Mesh is lying on xy plane in Blender, so z should be 0 in theory, but not in reality ...)
for element in plain_verts:
    exportString += "\t \"" + str(_pointCounter)+"\": [" + str(element[0])+", 0, " + str(element[1]) + "]"

    if _pointCounter < _iterationLength:
        _pointCounter += 1
        exportString += ","

    exportString += "\n"
    
exportString += "}"

# Exporting the file
exportFile = open("/Path/to/Export/file.json","w")
exportFile.write(exportString)
exportFile.close()
```

### Important facts

Rotating the `trackPath` in Step 8 is absolutely necessary. Otherwise, there is already in Blender a distortion along the positive z axis (Godot convention).

[image: Influence of Rotation]

## Questions:

1. Can there be any influence of the camera/viewport on the result of the vertex coordinate calculation (like a mix-up with screen space coordinates)? I could not find any change in outcome whilst playing with the related parameters (neither in the resulting path in Godot nor in a file diff of the json files). Even though I think this is a very unlikely cause, I would like to ask this question, because I encountered many oddities in Blender over the years...
2. Is this perhaps a rounding/float precision issue related to the bpy routine I am using?
3. Is there a better way to access/export the vertex coordinates out of Blender? I only need points, no edges/faces. Some of the solutions suggested in [this thread](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1311/how-can-i-get-vertex-positions-from-a-mesh) did throw an error in Blender 3.3... If possible, I would like to omit parsing complex export formats like stl/fbx/gtlf etc.

Comment: (1) No (2) Unlikely (3) It looks okay. Please attach the .blend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some even deeper investigation, I found the answer to the problem. There are two factors that contributed:

1. The Bézier Curve is slightly asymmetric. All the points are placed at the correct position, but the controls slightly differ between +Z and -Z. This is why the rotation by 180° mattered in the first place. However, this is only the reason why the discrepancy became obvious.
2. Blender and Godot use different coordinate systems.
   [image: Coordinate Systems: Godot vs. Blender]
   The Blender gtlf export takes this into account, however not my json export routine.

This can be fixed by modifying only one line in the original code:

```
exportString += "\t \"" + str(_pointCounter)+"\": [" + str(element[0])+", 0, " + str(-1*element[1]) + "]"
```

The change is `str(-1*element[1])`, which takes into account the "rotation" of the coordinate system, whereas the original `str(element[1])` does not.

Now the result is as expected:

[image: Godot: Comparison before/after z flip]

Additional confusion was created by the fact that the cameras I used for debugging were not oriented comparably (rotated by 180° around the x axis with respect to each other). This obscured the otherwise obvious issue of the z axis flipping.

In the end, it turned out to be a missing sign in the export routine, which due to conclusion derived from the wrong assumption about the object's symmetry and camera misalignment (due to user error) between Blender and Godot could stay unnoticed.